# Sports Programming

Tags: programming-languages, programming-practices

Other than programming, I'm addicted to sports. I'd like to integrate the two together. What are different programming languages that companies like ESPN use to work with stats? What techniques are used to do this, and how can I get going with it myself?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Statistical_programming_languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nobody can really answer this with certanty and yet cover everything, but my guess is that they use numerous languages, depending on the particular need at hand. For example, if you search for [available vacancies at ESPN](http://sports.espn.go.com/espn/jobs) you'll get a glimpse of what is used.

As far as techniques, most of it is rather fundamental statistics.

Answer (score 1):

[STATS](http://www.stats.com/broadcast.asp), a joint venture of the AP and News Corp, is one of the leading provider of statistics to broadcast networks like Fox and others.  Currently their [Careers](http://www.stats.com/careers.asp) page however only lists one position for a web developer for fantasy sports, so it is difficult to answer your question in more detail.